# External image added in android studio not working

Tags: image, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I downloaded external images to the android studio into the drawable folder of res but when I select the ImageView to add the same image on the screen, the image is not located there.

In the drawable folder, the image is being displayed with the red color, showing an error

How can I avoid this error or can use the external image on the android studio?

[This is what is being displayed after pasting the image in drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtJ0T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must know the drawable naming rules in Android

1 - The file name must not contain any space

2 - Use an underscore when using more than one word

Comment: I have tried the same thing changing the name of the image but it still not working, it is showing error

Comment: @xcapecoder what is wrong ?

Comment: Okay, it's working Amjad, thanks for helping me out. The issue was with the name of image - I edited it by deleting the special character and spaces